# How to list mounted ISO's and unmount them from the command line in VMware ESXi?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have a VMware ESXi 6 host with several guests running on it. There is a datastore with an ISO file that is in use by one or more of these clients.
I am accessing the ESXi host through ssh from linux, so PowerCLI is not an option.

Q1: How can I, from the VMware CLI, find out which guests have this ISO file mounted?

Q2: How can I, once I know that, unmount this ISO file from these guests, also from the VMware CLI?

I expect it to be `vim-cmd vmsvc` subcommands, but I haven't been able to find them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick & crude solution on the shell via SSH would be to write a small script that connects several actions:

1. Get your VM IDs with `vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms|awk '{print $1}'|grep -o -E '[0-9]+'` (list all VMs, only show first column with awk, filter out IPs and text and empty lines with grep)
2. Iterate over the lines (`ash` does not have arrays like `bash`) and check for each number/ID if one occurrence of your chosen ISO name is found in the device listing for each VM: `vim-cmd vmsvc/device.getdevices yourVmId|grep -o -A 12 -E 'yourImageName.iso' | grep -c 'connected = true'` (list all devices, get the area around your ISO file, check if the ISO is currently mounted/active)
3. Get the device ID of each CD drive (assuming it is only one, change the code for multiple drives on a single machine) with a modified grep from the same initial listing: `vim-cmd vmsvc/device.getdevices yourVmId|grep -o -B 4 -E 'yourImageName.iso'|grep -o -E 'key = [0-9]+'|grep -o -E '[0-9]+'` (double grep is neccessary because of missing group option `-P`)
4. Use `vim-cmd vmsvc/device.connection yourVmId yourDeviceId disconnect` to disconnect the device. *(Edit: It seems that this is not entirely correct, it does something, but not what I would expect. I'll update when I have time to investigate this further)*

The only problem I encountered is that the message "CD drive locked by guest" may appear in the VSphere client while doing the last step, but maybe this can be disabled generally.

Comment: Thanks for this very elaborate answer! The disconnect fails for me as well, but it seems to be the correct way to do it.

Comment: @rolek Glad I could help, thank you for accepting the answer. The strange thing I noticed is even after successful disconnect and state change in the Vsphere client, the hardware configuration window does not change - ISO is still mounted and in the same state. I did not test if this is only cosmetic, but I suspect there may be another way to remove the discs correctly.

Comment: (you're supposed to use PowerCLI)

Comment: @ewwhite Is PowerCLI available for Linux?

Answer (score 3):

[Use PowerCLI...](http://cloud.kemta.net/microsoft/powershell/powershell-vmware-list-all-vms-with-iso-mounted-and-dismount-them/)

Or just do it manually for the "several" VMs. 

Or avoid the situation in the first place by unmounting after installation.

Comment: Here is a PowerCLI onliner to disconnect all mounted VM ISOs: Get-VM | Get-CDDrive | Where {$_.ISOPath -ne $null} | Set-CDDrive -NoMedia -Confirm:$false Extracted from: http://www.sysadmit.com/2017/12/vmware-desconectar-cd-dvd-iso-PowerCLI.html